# Chrome web store newtab override with http request

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

To override the chrome web store new tab page I use the following code:

```
"chrome_url_overrides": {
  "newtab": "index.html"
}
```

I have a backend which serves the html files so instead of using the index.html file I would like to get a html file via a http request.

Is this possible? Or is there a workaround Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make an ajax call from your index page to remote server, and replace the entire html with external html. Sample code looks like the following

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
var SERVER_URL = "";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function() {
    replaceHtml(xhr.responseText);
};
xhr.open("GET", SERVER_URL);
xhr.send();

function replaceHtml(data) {
    document.open("text/html");
    document.write(data);
    document.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply have some javascript inside a `<script></script>` tag in your `index.html` file that grabs your generated html content from a custom domain.